# What is the correct way to prove the trigonometry identity $(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x) = \sin^4x + \sin^2 x \cos^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

See this simple equation:

$(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x) = \sin^4x + \sin^2 x \cos^2 x$

I have to prove that it's true. I did it like this:

$1 - \cos^2x = \sin^2x(\sin^2x + \cos^2x)$

$1-\cos^2x = \sin^2x$

So at the end I get that

$1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x$ and of course that's true.

But I got feedback I'm doing it wrong. A teacher told me that I should do it this way:

1. L = left side of the equation
2. R = right side of the equation
3. I can't mix L and R, I have to transform both (or at least one) separately.

I can't figure out why. Am I doing it wrong? If yes, why? May is it something like "my way or the highway"?

Comment: The right side of your first line after "I did it like this" sould not have that extra $+1$ inside the parentheses.

Comment: It's a stylistic decision. You can leave the left side in the original form and work $\sin ^2 x \rightarrow 1- \cos ^2 x \rightarrow (1-\cos x  )(1+ \cos x)$

Comment: your thought process is correct, But way of writing proof is incorrect, You already assumed L.H.S=R.H.S when you wrote $=$ sign, which was to be proved, What you have to do instead is that Manipulate L.H.S and R.H.S such that they finally become a same value, Then you can say L.H.S=R.H.S, for this case, Assume whatever you did to L.H.S and R.H.S separately and do what you did in your attempt and finally just write L.H.S=R.H.S,QED

Comment: The problem is that you're doing the argument in the wrong direction. You started by assuming the identity is true and ended up with something that's true, and then concluded the original identity is true. But that doesn't work in general: For example, if I start with $2 = 3$, then I conclude $2\cdot 0 = 3 \cdot 0$ and so $0=0$, which is true; therefore $2=3$. 

Instead, you could by noting that $1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x$ and $1-\cos^2x = \sin^2x$ and then multiplying LHS and RHS of the equations.

Comment: You *could* use your argument, but be careful to note that each of your implications also goes backward. $$1 - \cos^2x = \sin^2x(\sin^2x + \cos^2x) \iff 1-\cos^2x = \sin^2x \iff 1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x.$$  Then it's clear that you also have the forward direction,   $1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x \implies 1 - \cos^2x = \sin^2x(\sin^2x + \cos^2x)$, which is what you actually want to show.

Comment: @JairTaylor So I assumed that it's true and proved the assumption which may not be correct, yes? Now I understand why I rather should follow the teacher's way, but I think the way I presented is good in this case, because the task explicitly states "prove that its true", so it just must be true.

Comment: What if the question were "Decide whether this is true or false and show how you know"? @DheerajGujrathi has the best comment. Your argument is the analysis: the thought process that led you to believe the claim. But the correct final proof is the synthesis: starting from known things and ending with what you want to prove.

Comment: @Szyszka947 No, the logic is the same regardless of how the problem is phrased.  You know that it's true, but the problem is still to *prove* it, and in proving it you cannot assume that it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this because, You have assumed that $1 - \cos^2x = \sin^2x(\sin^2x + \cos^2x)$ is true (Which to be prove) and then g0t a true result $1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x$. You could not say that what you have assumed is true by getting true implication.

*Statement*$_{1}\Rightarrow$ *Statement*$_2$=true$, $Then *Statement*$_1$=*True* or *False*. That is why reverse implication is not always true. Here is a famous example: "A differentiable function is always continuous but the converse is not true which means a function may be continuous but not always differentiable."

So, you have to prove your statement as a consequence of something true like axioms or theorem. Here is a way to prove it:

[image]

By definition,

$\boxed{\sin \theta = \frac{AC}{AB}\\
\cos \theta = \frac{BC}{AB}}$

$$L.H.S{= (1 - \cos \theta)(1 + \cos \theta)\\
=(1- \frac{BC}{AB})(1+\frac{BC}{AB})\\
=1-\frac{BC^2}{AB^2}\\
=\frac{AB^2-BC^2}{AB^2}\\
=\frac{AC^2}{AB^2}\quad (\text{By Pythagorean theorem, } AB^2=AC^2+BC^2)}$$

$${R.H.S {= \sin^4\theta + \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta\\
=\frac{AC^4}{AB^4}+\frac{AC^2}{AB^2}\frac{BC^2}{AB^2}\\
=\frac{AC^4+AC^2BC^2}{AB^4}\\
=\frac{AC^2(AC^2+BC^2)}{AB^4}\\
=\frac{AC^2AB^2}{AB^4}\quad (\text{By Pythagorean theorem, } AB^2=AC^2+BC^2)\\
=\frac{AC^2}{AB^2}}}$$

L.H.S=R.H.S $\square$

Answer (score 2):

Your way is correct (even optimal, imo), provided you put a $\iff$ between each line, or better a $\impliedby$, which makes clearer that you are not assuming each line, but trying to justify it by the next line, which in turn will need to be justified:

$$(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x) = \sin^4x + \sin^2 x \cos^2 x$$
$$\impliedby 1 - \cos^2x = \sin^2x\left(\sin^2x + \cos^2x\right)$$
$$\impliedby 1-\cos^2x = \sin^2x$$
$$\impliedby 1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x$$
$$\impliedby\text{ TRUE.}$$

Note that (though admittedly less natural) a cheaper way uses the Pythagorean theorem $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ only once, at the end (whereas you also used it at the beginning):
$$(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x) = \sin^4x + \sin^2 x \cos^2 x$$
$$\impliedby 1 - \cos^2x-\sin^2x+\sin^2x = \sin^2x\left(\sin^2x + \cos^2x\right)$$
$$\impliedby 1+\sin^2x =\left(1+\sin^2x\right)\left(\sin^2x + \cos^2x\right)$$
$$\impliedby 1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x$$
$$\impliedby\text{ TRUE.}$$

Answer (score -1):

If your professor asks you to only work independently with each side we can do it this way. Start with the left side try to orient your methodology or approach to find the most simple terms of said equation with trigonometric identities.
The way to go is to transform complex things into simple terms. To help you in this case we only need the following identity:
$ \sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$